# Удалилась учетная запись win10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Сегодня было какое-то масштабное обновление в windows 10. После чего, компьютер перезагрузился и я увидел, что моя учетная запись администратора пропала, осталась только вторая запись, которая не была администраторской, но стала ей. При загрузке или при смене пользователя в списке учетных записей нет нужной учетки. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо сделать так:

1.Нажав и удерживая клавишу Windows, нажмите клавишу R (Win+R). Откроется диалог Выполнить | Run.

2.В поле Открыть | Open введите команду lusrmgr.msc.

3.Кликните на кнопку OK или нажмите Enter.

4.В левой панели кликните на папке Пользователи | Users. В центральной панели откроется список учетных записей вашей системы.

5.Кликните правым кликом на аккаунте Администратор | Administrator.

6.Во всплывшем меню выберите пункт Свойства | Properties.

7.Оставаясь во вкладке Общие | General, снимите флажок в чекбоксе Отключить учетную запись | Account is disabled.

8.Кликните на кнопку OK или нажмите Enter.